# Can I say "I'm making him understand this sum"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> 1. I'm making a pen.
> 2. I'm making a Toy.
> 3. i'm making him nervous.

So can I say "I'm making him understand this sum"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm making him understand this sum* is grammatical. One use of the verb *to make* is as a [causative](http://www.euenglish.hu/2016/01/causative/) in combination with an object and another verb. For example:

> - He made her wait.
> - She made him sleep on the sofa.

Semantically, however, the sentence is odd. Firstly, the causative *make* implies the existence of some force or threat. But you cannot enforce understanding. You would be unlikely to *make* me understand the general theory of relativity. But you can try to *help* me understand.

And secondly, the use of the continuous form *am making* implies that this is an ongoing process. This in turn implies that it is either a very complicated sum (arithmetical exercise or result of an addition problem?) or that the person you are helping is of limited cognitive ability.

Comment: It could also mean that there are unpleasant truths concealed by the complexity of the sum. For example the consequences of taking out a payday loan he can't afford at 1299% APR (and some of them are that high) could be disastrous but he might be set on doing just that.